# Identificacion de que tipo de variable recibe una propiedad de un objeto en Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo este pedazo de codigo que se aplica, si recibe un array de urls y paginas, lo itera buscando cada solicitud de las urls, o sea cada url y luego saca la etiqueta, que es la url

```
if (listingUrls && pages) {
  for (const req of listingUrls) {
    req.label = handlerLabels.listing;
    req.userData = { pages };
    await requestQueue.addRequest(req);
  }
}
```

sin embargo en la parte de `req.userData = { pages }` le pase esto para que lo leyera `"pages": ["1","1"]` y no lo toma
haciendo el debugger ejecuta hasta la linea de req.userData ya despues se cierra y me sale este error

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'label' on string 'https://www.shopdisney.com/star-wars-ahch-to-starbucks-mug-464061931497.html?isProductSearch=0&plpPosition=4'
```

que podria ser?

Comment: Cuál es el tipo de `req.label`? y qué le estás asignando? Qué es `handlerLabels.listing`? No sé si estoy en lo correcto, pero `req` parece ser del tipo `string`, y no tiene sentido para el compilador cuando le quieres agregar una propiedad.

Comment: el tipo de req.label es string y le asigne un array de urls pero cuando debuggeo agarra el primer url, handlerLabels.listing es esto export enum handlerLabels {
  detail = "ITEM_DETAIL",
  listing = "LISTING",
} un objeto que tiene dos propiedades